# empty response body in HTTP response in github actions

Tags: node.js, http, github-actions

I'm trying to create a github action which requires sending an http request to `https://www.instagram.com/<username>/?__a=1`.

When I'm running it locally, it runs perfectly fine and gives me the number of followers.

But when I use it in github actions, it isn't able to parse the JSON string as the response is null

Here is a link to the github action file https://github.com/ashawe/actions-check/blob/e80ca115544979cdb3180207b99c7724e4446849/index.js

Here is the code to get the followers ( starts at line #94 )

```
promiseArray.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const url = 'https://www.instagram.com/' + INSTAGRAM_USERNAME + '/?__a=1';
    core.info("url is");
    core.info(url);
    http.get(url, (response) => {
        let chunks_of_data = [];
        response.on('data', (fragments) => {
            chunks_of_data.push(fragments);
        });

        response.on('end', () => {
            let response_body = Buffer.concat(chunks_of_data);
            core.info(response_body.toString());
            let responseJSON = JSON.parse(response_body.toString());
            resolve((responseJSON.graphql.user.edge_followed_by.count).toString());
        });

        response.on('error', (error) => {
            reject(error);
        });
    });
}));
```

and then I'm processing it like:

```
Promise.allSettled(promiseArray).then((results) => {
    results.forEach((result, index) => {
        if (result.status === 'fulfilled') {
            // Succeeded
            //   core.info(runnerNameArray[index] + ' runner succeeded. Post count: ' + result.value.length);
            // postsArray.push(result.value);
            instagram_followers = result.value;
        } else {
            jobFailFlag = true;
            // Rejected
            //core.error(runnerNameArray[index] + ' runner failed, please verify the configuration. Error:');
            core.error(result.reason);
        }
    });
}).finally(() => {
    try {
        const followers = instagram_followers;
        const readmeData = fs.readFileSync(README_FILE_PATH, 'utf8');
        // core.info(readmeData);
        const shieldURL = "https://img.shields.io/badge/ %40 " + INSTAGRAM_USERNAME + "-" + followers + "-%23E4405F?style=for-the-badge&logo=instagram";
        const instagramBadge = "<img align='left' alt='instagram-followers' src='" + shieldURL + "' />";
        const newReadme = buildReadme(readmeData, instagramBadge);
        // core.info(newReadme);
        // if there's change in readme file update it
        if (newReadme !== readmeData) {
            core.info('Writing to ' + README_FILE_PATH);
            fs.writeFileSync(README_FILE_PATH, newReadme);
            if (!process.env.TEST_MODE) {
                // noinspection JSIgnoredPromiseFromCall
                commitReadme();
            }
        } else {
            core.info('No change detected, skipping');
            process.exit(0);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        core.error(e);
        process.exit(1);
    }
});
```

But when I run the action, it gives this error:
[image]

which means that the response_body isn't complete JSON response but a request to https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/?__a=1 does send a json response.

Comment: Update: I'm deleting the github repository. Basically insta won't let me access the data from the github network. Therefore, I have to create a fb app, an instagarm app, add myself as a tester, authorize myself, get a code and then exchange the code for a short lived authorization token (valid for an hour only) and use this token to get followers. I can get a long lived token but it is valid for 2 months meaning i have to refresh it before it expires. All this just to get the number of followers seems unreasonable so i'm dropping the project (which was to create IG follower badge for GH readme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Basically every time you hit that endpoint it returns the login html page, which causes the json parse to fail. It appears that you may need to use the api which requires you to authenticate before getting info from users. Or figure out other scraping methodologies.

I was able to recreate this failure in my local pc by jumping into a vpn and private browser. When I hit the endpoint it took me to the login screen. And when i hit the endpoint through curl in terminal it returned nothing. But when i got off the vpn, all worked fine. I think the reason it worked in your local is because there's some caching happening in the browser and you're probs not in a vpn. I am thinking there's some network blacklisting happening when on vpn. I don't know the github hosted network so I would recommend opening a ticket with them if you want to learn more about that.

Here are the instagram api docs for quick reference
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started

**Previews Response:** Leaving here for other users future reference.

You are not passing username so it's trying to query the endpoint with empty username

Instead of running just node index.js in your action, you need to call your action and provide it with the parameters that it needs

```
  - name: Your github action
    uses: ./ # Uses an action in the root directory
    with:
      username: '_meroware'
```

Then your code will pick it put properly

```
  const INSTAGRAM_USERNAME = core.getInput('username');
  const url = 'https://www.instagram.com/' + INSTAGRAM_USERNAME + '/?__a=1';
```

Resources:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-javascript-action

Comment: No. I am passing the username. Check https://github.com/ashawe/instagram-followers/blob/main/.github/workflows/test.yml This is where I'm using that action.
And check Line 84 of the action's index.js https://github.com/ashawe/actions-check/blob/e80ca115544979cdb3180207b99c7724e4446849/index.js#L84

Comment: @ashawe thanks for sharing your code, it helped to debug the problem much easier. I think it's an authentication issue and details are in the response.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for bringing that to my attention, I tried using that endpoint in a private browser on both desktop and phone and it seemed to work fine. When I tried it using an VPN as you said, it took me to a login page. I'll try to use the API key now! Thanks

Comment: The API wants me to ask the user for the user's access token and then it will provide the user info. So basically, I can get the follower count neither directly nor via the api (without authorization). So, I guess I would have to just scrape now.

UPDATE: It also won't let me see the profile when using a VPN. idk what to do